# Combining shape and color of the legends in vegalite

Tags: javascript, visualization, vega-lite

I'm trying to make the legend of my line chart adopt the set of colors and shapes I created (instead of red dot and triangle, make it red triangle). It works while creating the single chart, but as I concatenate the chart with another chart horizontally, the legends start overriding and became illegible. Any idea why?

[image]

```
      vl.color().fieldN('ProblemType').scale(colors).legend({orient: 'top-left'}),
      vl.shape().fieldN('ProblemType').scale(shapes).legend({orient: 'top-left'})
```

Answer (score 0):

Under most circumstances, Vega-Lite will automatically combine color and shape legends. For example ([vega editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4KABGBEAmCGAutIC4zEgVwE4BsVTkQHoBjWLAZwDoArCgewDtIBfAGnCgFtyBrfSAAd6AS0bxIHCJACmjEvWhiA5vlARpCnPSxrIAMxEyc0AQHksI5WMlR4AT0EyBjelzGw87TtIoALWCc9Q2NTVEgLKxs2O0dncNd3Rk9WKQ1IAA9goxMBAFkRHBkKAH0nLBKAcU9tZhjIByDwgEcMWHERRHgRADdnbw0oe2zQgQAJHQoZYQB3GV16xvioVvburt7+zhYQFiA)):

```
{
  "data": {"url": "data/cars.json"},
  "mark": "point",
  "encoding": {
    "color": {"field": "Origin", "type": "nominal"},
    "shape": {"field": "Origin", "type": "nominal"},
    "x": {"field": "Miles_per_Gallon", "type": "quantitative"},
    "y": {"field": "Horsepower", "type": "quantitative"}
  }
}
```

[image]

If you're seeing different results, I'd suggest sharing a minimal example that reproduces the issue you're seeing: absent that it will be difficult to give any concrete advice.